# Monitoring Tomcat StandardThreadExecutor's queue size (MBean)

Tags: java, tomcat

Tomcat's standard executor has a queue which stores requests which cannot be processed currently, if all executor threads are busy.
The size of the queue can be configured. The standard value is Integer.MAX_VALUE (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html)

I'd like to know the current size of that queue as it would IMO be a good indicator of whether the number of worker threads cannot handle the number of requests.
However, I haven't found any way to access it - e.g. as MBean.
Has anyone succeeded in getting that information?

Comment: D'oh, I just realized that I had no Executor defined in my server.xml (was using the standard one from mvn tomcat7:run). No wonder I couldn't find the MBean.
When I add an Executor, I can easily find the MBean under Catalina:type=Executor,name=<name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh, I just realized that I had no Executor defined in my server.xml (was using the standard one from mvn tomcat7:run). No wonder I couldn't find the MBean.

When I add an Executor, I can easily find the MBean under Catalina:type=Executor,name=[name]